# How to implement Drop Down Box that loads element on select?

Tags: c#, html, css, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I'm creating a webpage and I'd like to implement a drop down list that loads a specific `.jpg` somewhere else on the same page when the user selects an option from aforementioned box. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 & I'm looking to implement this in pure HTML rather than CSS or C# code.. But if I have to use either of the 2 then fine.

This drop down list is filled in from a database. Just in case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a SelectedIndexChanged event on the drop down list and set AutoPostBack for the control to true.

In the SelectedIndexChanged event, programmatically add the image.

Comment: Is this through .ASP ? Or C# ?

Comment: That would be with C#, or VB.Net I believe.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what user1948635 says, Yes it is through ASP and you can do this inside an `UpdatePanel` using the  `ScriptManager` so that you don't have to refresh the whole page in the DropDownList's postback event and just refresh that specific part (.Net AJAX feature)